# CSS - How to show text on hover of class and class::before

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using CSS I have created a screen split into 4 sections and on hover of each section I need to blur the background and show a text middle of the section. I am not able to achieve the expected result.

```js
function onSplitLeftEnter(event) {
  if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-left')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-left').style.opacity = 1;
  } else if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-left::before')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-remaining-left').style.opacity = 1;
  }
}

function onSplitLeftLeave(event) {
  if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-left')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-left').style.opacity = 0;
  } else if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-left::before')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-remaining-left').style.opacity = 0;
  }
}

function onSplitRightEnter(event) {
  if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-right')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-right').style.opacity = 1;
  } else if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-right::before')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-remaining-right').style.opacity = 1;
  }
}

function onSplitRightLeave(event) {
  if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-right')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-right').style.opacity = 0;
  } else if (event.target === document.querySelector('.split-bottom-right::before')) {
    document.querySelector('.content-remaining-right').style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.split-screen {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.split-bottom-left,
.split-bottom-right {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.split-bottom-left::before,
.split-bottom-right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.split-bottom-left::before {
  background-color: green;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.split-bottom-right::before {
  background-color: red;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.split-bottom-left {
  background-color: black;
}

.split-bottom-right {
  background-color: pink;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.75s;
}

.content-left {
  left: 75%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content-right {
  left: 25%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content-remaining-left {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content-remaining-right {
  top: 25%;
  left: 75%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-screen">
  <div class="split-bottom-left" onmouseenter="onSplitLeftEnter(event)" onmouseleave="onSplitLeftLeave(event)">
    <div class="content content-left">
      <h2>Bottom Left</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content content-remaining-left">
      <h2>Remaining Left</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split-bottom-right" onmouseenter="onSplitRightEnter(event)" onmouseleave="onSplitRightLeave(event)">
    <div class="content content-right">
      <h2>Bottom Right</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content content-remaining-right">
      <h2>Remaining Right</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I am not able to achieve the expected result` - Ok, so what *is* the expected result? You say you need to blur the background, but there doesn't appear to be any background to blur

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, on hover of split-bottom-left::before space blur the background color of this class, show the content-left and on hover of split-bottom-left need to blur the background color of split-bottom-left show content-remaining-left. similarly for right too.

Comment: You can't attach event handlers to pseudo-elements, so if you need that behaviour you'll need to come up with another method of creating the split UI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Is there any way in JavaScript to figure out the regular and pseudo-elements using pointer location? or in CSS any way around?

Comment: If you know the coordinates you can try and use `getBoundingClientRect()` in combination with `document.elementFromPoint()` and see if the elements matches.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same UI without using pseudo class